# Adding 2 Tables into Footer or Header

Tags: vba, ms-word

1. I'm trying to add a table to a Footer which can be done. However, once i create the second table I have

> 6028 error : the range cannot be deleted.

If i swap tables it creates a table and another one within it. which is not my goal. Want to create two separated tables, Allow them to overlap each other.

2. Once i enter the dimensions, add `RelativeHorizontalPositionPage`, `set RowsHeight` and add `.Rows.Allowoverlap = True`, it gives me another

> Error 5149 The measurement must be between 0 cm and 55,87 centimetres.

I know i'm doing something wrong, just cant figure what. This is what i want to get eventually

[image]

Any help would be apprecieted.

```
Set oHF = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage)


Set aTable2 = oHF.Range.Tables.Add(Range:= _
oHF.Range, Numrows:=1, NumColumns:= _
3, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord8TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
        wdAutoFitFixed)

With aTable2

'.Rows.AllowOverlap = True
.Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderDiagonalDown).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
.Borders(wdBorderDiagonalUp).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
.Rows.SetHeight RowHeight:=CentimetersToPoints(0.5), _
HeightRule:=wdRowHeightAtLeast
.Rows.RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
.Rows.RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage

.Rows.HorizontalPosition = CentimetersToPoints(2)
.Rows.VerticalPosition = CentimetersToPoints(25.25)
End With

Set aTable = oHF.Range.Tables.Add(Range:= _
oHF.Range, Numrows:=8, NumColumns:= _
1, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord8TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
        wdAutoFitFixed)
With aTable

'.Rows.AllowOverlap = True
.Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderDiagonalDown).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
.Borders(wdBorderDiagonalUp).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
.Rows.SetHeight RowHeight:=CentimetersToPoints(0.5), _
HeightRule:=wdRowHeightAtLeast

.Rows.RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
.Rows.RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage

.Rows.HorizontalPosition = CentimetersToPoints(2)
.Rows.VerticalPosition = CentimetersToPoints(25.25)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim HdFt As HeaderFooter, Tbl As Table
With ActiveDocument
  Set HdFt = .Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage)
  Set Tbl = .Tables.Add(Range:=HdFt.Range.Characters.Last, Numrows:=1, NumColumns:=3, _
    DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord8TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed)

  'Process 1st table
  With Tbl
    'including:
    .Rows.WrapAroundText = True
  End With

  Set Tbl = .Tables.Add(Range:=HdFt.Range.Characters.Last, Numrows:=8, NumColumns:=1, _
    DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord8TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed)

  'Process 2nd table
  With Tbl

  End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That helped. Thank you very much.